# Populate base class using IOptions pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to populate a base class using the `IOptions` pattern.

My question -- When I populate the derived object `Child`, is it possible to populate the `Base` object as well without having to reference it within the `Child` code AND without having to uncomment the commented line[1] in "Startup" below?

Config:

```
<Child>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Username>jdoe</username>
</Child>
```

Startup:

```
services.Configure<Child>(Configuration.GetSection("Child"));

//will work if this line is uncommented
//services.Configure<Base>(Configuration.GetSection("Child")); //[1]
```

Objects:

```
public class Base {    
    public int Id {get;set;}    
}

public class Child : Base {    
    public string Username {get;set;}    
}
```

Service:

```
public class BaseService {
    private readonly Base _cfg;

    public BaseService(IOptions<Base> cfg) { _cfg = cfg.Value; }

    public void Get() {

         //does not work
         //returns null
         var _id = _cfg.Id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally resolved this by using generic constraints

```
public class BaseService<T> : where T : Base, new() {

    private readonly Base _cfg;

    public BaseService(IOptions<T> Tcfg) {
        _cfg = Tcfg.Value;
    }

    public void Get() {

          //works now
          var _id = _cfg.Id;
    }
}
```

Startup Service DI

`services.AddScoped<BaseService<Child>>();`